# devbridge autocomplte ignore part of the search field

Tags: jquery

I used Devbridge autocomplete to make a search in a database similar with google maps. the user need to input the address, and I will search using autocomplete in a table with 51k records. I have the following fields:
    - city
    - street type (street, alley, blvd, etc)
    - street name
    - postcode

I am doing the search only on the street name.

I need to ignore some part of the input. For example, 99% of the users will type "street abc" or "alley abc" instead of abc.

I want to have something like
    - when user enter words like "str, street, alley, etc" to not happen anything
    - when user will start to enter street name, to show suggestions based on db query

Here is the code

```
$('#address').autocomplete({
     serviceUrl: './test.php',
    onSelect: function(suggestion) {
        $('#valoare').html('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
    },
    onHint: function (hint) {
        $('#valoare').val(hint);
    },
    onInvalidateSelection: function() {
        $('#selction-ajax').html('You selected: none');
    }
});
```

I try to ignore get in PHP, but no luck. Anybody have any idea how to solve this?
Thank you

UPDATE - PHP Code with comments

```
/*if ($_GET['query'] != 's' || $_GET['query'] != 'S')
   if ($_GET['query'] != 'st' || $_GET['query'] != 'St')
    if ($_GET['query'] != 'str' || $_GET['query'] != 'Str')
        if ($_GET['query'] != 'str' || $_GET['query'] != 'Str') {*/


            $results = $database->select("carrier_pcodes", "*", ["nume_artera[~]" => $_GET['query']]);

            $suggestions = array();


            $reply['query'] = $_GET['query'];
            $reply['suggestions'] = array();

            foreach ($results as $result) {


                $reply['suggestions'][] = array(
                    'value' => $result['tip_artera'] . ' ' . $result['nume_artera'] . ', ' . $result['localitate'] . ', ' . $result['judet'] . ', ' . $result['cod'],
                    'data' => "madalin",
                );

            }

            echo json_encode($reply);  
/*         }
          else echo json_encode(array());
      else echo json_encode(array());
  else echo json_encode(array());*/
```

Comment: Can you provide your PHP code too ?

Comment: I made an update to my original post with PHP code